# Override Marionette.Region's getEl method in Backbone.Marionette

Tags: javascript, layout, backbone.js, marionette, regions

I've set up a project where I've extended a `Backbone.Marionette.Layout` that contains two different regions. This layout can be used as a component throughout the application. In particular, the regions are set up like the following.

```
regions : {
    masterRegion : { selector: '[data-region=master]' },    
    slaveRegion: { selector: '[data-region=slave]' }
},
```

In particular, I'm using a `data-region` selector to inject the view I'm interested in.

When such a layout is used in a tree structure views are duplicated since `getEl` function adresses the wrong region to inject the view. Obviously it's my fault and within `Marionette` (v1.1.0) doc the following is written.

> override the getEl function if we have a parentEl this must be
>   overridden to ensure the selector is found on the first use of the
>   region. if we try to assign the region's el to parentEl.find(selector)
>   in the object literal to build the region, the element will not be
>   guaranteed to be in the DOM already, and will cause problems

where `getEl` is defined as

```
getEl: function(selector){
    return Marionette.$(selector);
}
```

So, my question is the following. What does this mean? How can I override this method? Where is the correct to perform such an override?

Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my understanding of this:

- the points below apply to the case where the layout is contained within another element ("if we have a parentEl")
- the first time you use a region, Marionette needs to select the proper DOM element to populate, according to the selector string ("ensure the selector is found on the first use of the region")
- you can't simply look for the selector in the parentEl ("if we try to assign the region's el to parentEl.find(selector) in the object literal"), because the DOM element we want isn't necessarily in the DOM yet ("the element will not be guaranteed to be in the DOM already")

In other words, the first time you use a region (e.g. with a call to the `show` method), Marionette needs to build a region instance and associate it with the correct DOM element (specified by the `selector`attribute).

However, before Marionette can look for the DOM element within the containing parent element, it must ensure that all required DOM elements (most importantly the one we're looking for) have loaded.

Does that make more sense to you?

Edit based on flexaddicted's comment.

> Could you suggest me a the correct way to achieve this? Is there any
>   manner to override the method below?

I don't think you need to override this method. The comment indicates why the DOM element is fetched that way instead of by direct assignment when the region is built, but it should still work properly with a tree structure (since parents can still be determined properly).

I think the problem might be with your region selector: as it is "generic", it can potentially match multiple elements (as opposed to selecting with an `id` attribute that should match only 1 element), and could be matching a DOM element you're not expecting such as a child view. (This of course depends on when Marionette looks at the DOM to fetch the selector.)

Also, I'd consider using a composite view for your tree structure needs if possible. See http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/02/03/tutorial-nested-views-using-backbone-marionettes-compositeview/ and http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply. +1. Could you suggest me a the correct way to achieve this? Is there any manner to override the method below?

Comment: Davis, thank you very much. I'll also have a look to the sources above. Have a nice day.

Comment: Sorry for the final "s", David ;)